# Alternate method for setHours() of java.util.Date?

Tags: java

What is an alternate method for `setHours()` of `java.util.Date` as it is deprecated. To my date variable, I want to set certain hours but I don't want to use the deprecated method `setHours()`.

Comment: Use a GregorianCalendar. Or switch to JODA time which is a popular alternative to the Date libraries in the SDK.

Answer (score 47):

Try this:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
 Date date = cal.getTime();
```

If you have a `Date` object already, you can use `cal.setTime(date)` to initialize calendar with the given date.

**JavaDoc** for `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`

> Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day.
>   HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM
>   the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.

Answer (score 26):

Instead of using `Date` class functions which are deprecated you can use `Calendar` class.

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(YOUR_DATE_OBJECT);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
Date date=calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can save/set the DATE parameters using Java Calendar object methods.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.setTime(YOUR_DATE);
now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
YOUR_DATE = now.getTime();
```